# How to distinguish RPC payload data length?

Tags: c++, json, grpc, rpc

RPC can be implemented in many ways.

And we should know that, fixed RPC payload is actually difficult to use. Different RPC method has different RPC payload (method parameter).

I'm confusing about how to distinguish a payload's data length ?

For example, I've designed RPC protocols below using JSON:

protocol 1:

```
{
  "method": "sayHello",
  "parameter": "UserName",
  "return": "Hello! UserName!"
}
```

method 1:

```cpp
std::string sayHello(const std::string &user_name);
```

protocol 2:

```
{
  "method": "sayBye",
  "parameter": "UserName",
  "return": "Goodbye! UserName"
}
```

method 2:

```cpp
std::string sayBye(const std::string &user_name);
```

I'm going to use a JSON serialization library to encode these information into a string, which is my RPC payload. For example method 1's payload length is 20, method 2's payload length is 34. I use socket to send 2 payload.

Then my server just read as many bytes as it can. It will read 54 (20 + 34) bytes, and seems got an error when decoding!

But how can the server realize there're 2 payloads ?

I'm coming up with an idea: put a fixed 8 byte at the beginning of JSON payload. This fixed-length 8 byte contains the JSON payload's length. So the server can firstly read 8 byte, then it will know how many bytes are there in the following JSON payload.

After update, the protocols is:

```
|--8 byte--|--JSON payload--|
```

But this solutions seems raw and ugly. Is there any elegant and very good solutions ?

Comment: Isn't checking the `} ` enough to act as a separator in the json ?

Comment: You'd probably hvae to implement your own json parser which stops when it reaches the end of a document, just using the industry standard technique of prefixing messages with their length is much simpler and more robust

Comment: @AlanBirtles, thanks to reply. Would you please share more information about *industry standard technique of prefixing messages* ?

Comment: You're already using it

Comment: @Clonk, I understand thank you!